# How to add text to an adjacent cell based on string values

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to make a `CSV` import macro system that imports, formats and simplifies the data enclosed. I have, up to this point, gotten the file imported and formatted for the most part. At this point, I am trying to add a column adjacent to `A:A` and, based off of a file suffix, put the related term in the new column.

I've tried using `.Find` functions, and am currently trying to work with a For loop, with an `If InStr` function enclosed.

```
Sub FileExtentionAddition()                                                    

    ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Select             'Adding the adjacent column
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    Dim SearchRange As Range, Cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2

    Dim LastRow As String                      'Creates Variable for Last Row
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count       'Defines Last Row Number

    Set SearchRange = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)'Restricts For Loop to used cells

        For Each Cell In SearchRange

            If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, ".SLDPRT") > 0 Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Part"
            ElseIf InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, ".SLDASM") Then
                ActiveCell.Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Assembly"
            ElseIf InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, ".SLDDRW") Then
                ActiveCell.Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Drawing"
            Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Other"
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Currently running this with a file gives me 0 added text in column B, with no errors at all. I have tried using Debug.Print to read ActiveCell.Value but from what I can tell, there isn't anything being read. I'm fairly new to VBA so hopefully I am just missing something.

Comment: Use `Cell`, not `ActiveCell`.

Comment: Switching it back gives the same issues, doesn't change much, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cell as a variable is a bad idea, cell already has a built in meaning.

```
dim lastrow as long
dim i as long
dim cellval as string

with activesheet ' You should make this an explicit reference
    lastrow = .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row
    for i = 2 to lastrow
        cellval = .cells(i, "A").value
        if instr(1, cellval, ".SLDPRT") then
            .cells(i, "B").value = "Part"
        elseif instr(1, cellval, ".SLDASM") then
            .cells(i, "B").value = "ASSEMBLY"
        elseif InStr(1, cellval, ".SLDDRW") Then
            .cells(i, "B").Value = "Drawing"
        else
            .cells(i, "B").value = "Other"
        end if
    next i
end with
```

Comment: Hey Warcupine, That's fair, I didn't really realize that it had a set meaning by itself.
I tried out your code, and the for loop doesn't seem to even activate, just gets skipped over. Do I need to add anything to it?

Comment: I didn't put the top of your code, lastrow isn't actually being set if you copy pasted

Comment: I'm running it with all of the variables defined, but am still getting a 1004 Runtime Error. Any guesses?

Comment: is ```lastrow = .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row``` within the ```with``` statement? I'm guessing it is a range issue, on what line does it fail?

Comment: It is failing on `cellval = .Cells(iter, "A").Value` right now. I've been trying a bunch of other things, and no matter what method that I use it's always defining the string to be searched in `inStr` that doesn't seem to work

Comment: aha i declared ```i``` and then used ```iter``` that will probably fix it. Assuming you are using ```option explicit``` (which you should be).

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!